# Why is the database diagrams view still showing dropped tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using SQLServer 2005 I have dropped some tables (via a T-SQL query) and they are still showing as tables when creating a database diagram!

Already tried refreshing, disconnecting and reconnecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Management Studio keeps a cache (even after disconnecting)

Quitting and restarting seemed to fix it.